# samples in aggregate report in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am running a test for testing if my application is able to handle 250 concurrent users or not.first time when I ran the test,results were fine and number of samples generated in aggregate report is also fine but when I am running the same test again,i am getting drastic changes in aggregate report.This time number of samples got reduced and also the response time got higher.Whereas cpu usage and memory usage is fine and database server performance is also good.For this I am using stepping thread group.
please help me to get rid out of it.

Answer (score 1):

What about CPU and RAM usage on the host, you're running JMeter on? Make sure that:

1. You running JMeter [in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
2. You have all the listeners disabled
3. You have only absolutely minimum of pre/post processors and assertions added/enabled
4. JMeter has enough JVM heap space (70-80% of your total physical RAM)

See [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](https://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) for detailed explanations and more JMeter configuration tricks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the logic your application has you might not be able to handle 250 threads on single machine (not enough computing resources RAM, NIC bandwidth etc) You haven't provided details about your machine utilization during the run test and Jmeter logs for any warnings or errors. Check that.

We had the same kind of issues when we were testing heavy application (with sessions and long user flows). [Master-slave](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) config can fully resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.My machine utilisation is normal.My machine has 8 GB RAM and dual core processor.Also in there are no errors or warning logs observed during test run.In first run same with same configuration I got fine results.